# Wicked_pdf and wkhtmltopdf not encoding pdf correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

Hi am successfully creating a PDF invoice both on development and staging (ubuntu).

However, on production, when i access the url to see the PDF, the browser complains that the pdf cannot be viewed correctly.

I tried to save it and opened it and i realized that the file is not encoded but i can see the full HTML code that is used to create the template.

If i use wkhtmltopdf from my command line it works fine, so it could be a routing problem?

Answer (score 0):

try using encoding while creating pdf

```
encoding: "UTF-8"
```